# REST API for user profiles with different attributes

Tags: rest

I am trying to create a REST API for user profiles on a car website. In my case each user profile has a car, which depending on the brand may have different attributes.

Right now I capture a POST request on `/profiles/{profile_name}`. The following shows an example json payload

```
{
    "car_brand" : "BMW",
    "car_data" : {
        "engine_size" : "2.0L",
        "top_speed" : 200
        ...
        "special_bmw_attribute" : "bmw logo color"
    }
}
```

Once the request hits my backend I check the `car_brand` value and create a `Car` object by calling the corresponding car constructor with the data from `car_data`. I then create a `UserProfile` object with the `profile_name` and which has the created car as an attribute. Lastly I store this `UserProfile` object in my database.

Is this a solid approach, or is there a better or simpler way? What pitfalls should I be wary of? I have limited experience with REST APIs and would like to know if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: Your question is not about the API but about data model. Share you DB structure and class diagram and we will see if any optimizations are possible. Once you design the model, you can tailor REST API to that, not the other way round.

Comment: Yeah I can see that the question got a bit loose. Mostly wondering if the car_brand and related car_data keys are a typical way of accommodating different attributes. I thought you tailored the API around usability and not backend logic. Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Well, I meant that if there are any pitfalls hidden behind your implementation, they are in the model, not API. When talking about API, I think you answered your question: if it's only usable from client's perspective, then it is totally fine. Consider though, extraction of the attributes that are common to all the brands (engine_size, top_speed etc) to a separate object. All the others should preferably be treated as a map of auxiliary attributes.